# flex for dynamic layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create dynamic layout with flex for video conference app. I want all the videos to appear in same row and use 100% height. PFB the code I have written. This works for two videos but the third video moves in next row also the video is not consuming the 100% height.

```
.containervid {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    @media (orientation:portrait) {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}

.items {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex: 1 1 0;
}

 video {
    position: relative;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML structure? Take a look at this guide on [giving us examples from which we can see the problem directly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I just made a quick code pen, it's a pretty simple example but should do what you're looking for. It uses bootstrap to just define the column size you want which you can adjust or just use `col` to have a dynamic column width.

https://codepen.io/sean-mooney/pen/KKdRqXJ

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi @Sean Mooney, Thanks for the input, but I want the layout to be dynamic. So if there is only one person in conference, the video should occupy 100% width and 100% height. If there are two person 100% height and 50% width, with 3 person 100% height and 33.3% width.

Comment: @AnupamChaplot You really should include this in your original question. Would you mind editing your question to [reclarify what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ;-)? Future responders shouldn't have to search through comments of other answers to **get the specification of the question**.